# change Top app bar default stroke color in compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to change the default top app bar stroke color that that jet pack provides.
so far I've tried changing elevation to 0.dp but it doesn't help.

[image: top app bar stroke color]

I'm trying to blend the color of background with top app bar color.
is there's any way to remove the grey stroke color of top app bar in compose?

Comment: Provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the elevation of the Toolbar, I think it's just the shadow.

```
elevation = 0.dp
```